# How can I capture included property names in a JSON web api request with asp.net core?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, jsonconverter

I am building an asp.net core web api and I need to keep track of properties that were actually included in a JSON body, since .NET doesnt have the concept of undefined as in javascript, just null.

I created an interface which all of my models implement which is just a string array called IncludedProperties:

```
string[] IncludedProperties {get; set;}
```

I might have models which have more of these models nested inside.  Any time I am deserializing one of these models, I want it to populate this list of IncludedProperties.

For example, in my controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> PatchModel([FromRoute]Guid id, [FromBody] RootModel model) { ... }
```

And classes are is defined as:

```
public class RootModel : IIncludedProperties
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public NestedModel SubEntity { get; set;}
    public string[] IncludedProperties {get; set;}
}

public class NestedModel : IIncludedProperties
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public decimal Value {get; set;}
   public string[] IncludedProperties {get; set;}
}
```

If the JSON body is as follows:

```
{
    "Name": "New Entity 01",
    "SubEntity": {
        "Name": "Child Entity 01",
        "Value": 0.5
    }
}
```

The included properties for the root would be `[ "Name", "SubEntity"]` and the included properties for the nested model would be `[ "Name", "Value" ]`.

I am going through the documentation from Microsoft on [custom converters for JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to), but it seems I will need to rewrite the entire json converter just to add in a bit of extra functionality.  Is there any way I could "plug in" to the existing converter, just to capture the included property names?

Comment: You want InclucedProperties to be an array that holds the names or values, of the attributes of the json object?

Comment: The names of the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with reflection and recursion. If you don't mind adding one more line inside each controller, you can call this function after model binding:

```
void PopulateIncludedProperties(IIncludedProperties obj)
{
    var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
    obj.IncludedProperties = properties
        .Where(p => p.Name != "IncludedProperties" && p.GetValue(obj) != null)
        .Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        var value = prop.GetValue(obj);
        if (value is IIncludedProperties includedPropValue)
        {
            PopulateIncludedProperties(includedPropValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Please customize yourself if you want to populate `IncludedProperties` of an `IEnumerable<IIncludedProperties>`